# How can I incorporate both iOS 9.3 & iOS 10 codes into my App?

Tags: swift3, ios10

Scenario: 
I have an existing iOS 9.3 application that my 5th-Generation iTouch can handle.  
I want to add iOS 10-savvy code to this application and be able to filter it from the existing code so I can continue working with my old iTouch.

However, the compiler refuses to build if the **Deployment Target** is set at iOS 9.3 or lower:

[image]

Is there a work-around or must I create a new application?

---

Possible solution:

1. Build for iOS 10.0+ deployment; then
2. Filter via in-code @available(iOS 10.0, *).

My iTouch can't handle iOS 10; so I'm hope the above solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

you use #available

```
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: {
            (success) in
            guard success else {
                //Handle error
                return
            }
        })
    } else {
        _ = UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yah... It just occurred to me.   Makes sense.